# How to exit last entry only in a pyramiding strategy?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to figure out how to close last entry(s) only when it's profitable in a pyramiding strategy and leave others that are not in profit open. So far it is not working. Here is my code:

```
lastEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
if short and strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, limit=close)
    strategy.exit("E_S1", "Short", profit = profit)
    
if short and close > lastEntryPrice
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, limit=close)
    strategy.exit("E_S1", "Short", profit = profit)

if strategy.position_size < 0 and lastEntryPrice > close and strategy.opentrades != 1
    strategy.exit("E_S2", "Short", limit=close)
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing `lastEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)`, you are only referring to the last entry price even if you have multiple trades open.

You can just loop over the open trades and check whether they are in profit or not. Also, give unique ids to each trade so you can control which one of them you are closing.

Here is a small example for you. I was able to reproduce a test case very early on on BTCUSD, 1D timeframe.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=5)

var cnt = 1

sma1 = ta.sma(close, 20)
sma2 = ta.sma(close, 40)
sma3 = ta.sma(close, 100)

plot(sma1, color=color.green)
plot(sma2, color=color.yellow)
plot(sma3, color=color.red)

if (ta.crossover(sma1, sma2))
    entry_id = "Long " + str.tostring(cnt)
    strategy.entry(entry_id, strategy.long)
    cnt := cnt + 1

if (ta.crossunder(sma2, sma3))
    for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
        entry_trade = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(i)
        entry_comment = strategy.opentrades.entry_comment(i)
        in_profit = strategy.opentrades.profit(i) > 0

        if (in_profit)
            strategy.close(entry_trade, comment=entry_comment)
```

[image]

As you can see, when the exit condition is triggered (cross under), only `Long 6` and `Long 7` are closed. `Long 8` which is not in profit at the time is still open.